# problems with 2D elastic collision in java

Tags: java, collision

I'am having problem in getting the velocity after collision between two balls. 
I have this function that get's the velocity of the two balls after collision in java code.

```
   { Ball a,b;

    double theta=Math.atan2(b.getY()-a.getY(),b.getX()-a.getX());//angle of rotation of axis

    //m1 and m2 are the mass of the two balls
    float m1=a.getMass();float m2=b.getMass();




    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double V1angle=Math.atan2(a.getVelocityy(),a.getVelocityx());
    double V1=Math.abs(a.getVelocityx())*Math.abs(Math.cos(V1angle))+Math.abs(a.getVelocityy())*Math.abs(Math.sin(V1angle));//V1 is the velocity of ball a before collision
    double V2angle=Math.atan2(b.getVelocityy(),b.getVelocityx());
    double V2=Math.abs(b.getVelocityx())*Math.abs(Math.cos(V2angle))+Math.abs(b.getVelocityy())*Math.abs(Math.sin(V2angle));//V2 is the velocity of ball b before collision

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   //calculating the new x and y velocity in the new system of ball a and b

   double V1x=Math.cos(V1angle-theta)*V1;//V1x is the x velocity of ball a 
   double V2x=Math.cos(V2angle-theta)*V2;//V2x is the x velocity of ball b 




   double V1y=Math.sin(V1angle-theta)*V1;//V1y is the y velocity of ball a
   double V2y=Math.sin(V2angle-theta)*V2;//V2y is the y velocity of ball b




    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



     //calculating the final x and y velocity of the two balls after collision in the new system

    double U1x=((m1-m2)*V1x)/(m1+m2)+((2*m2))*V2x/(m1+m2);


    double U2x=((m2-m1)/(m1+m2))*V2x+((2*m1)/(m1+m2))*V1x;


    double U1y=((m1-m2)/(m1+m2))*V1y+((2*m2)/(float)  (m1+m2))*V2y;
    double U2y=((m2-m1)/(m1+m2))*V2y+(   (2*m1)/(m1+m2))*V1y;

     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    double U11x=U1x,U11y=U1y,U22x=U2x,U22y=U2y;


    //converting x and y velocity in the new rotated system back to the main system
    U1x=U11x*Math.cos(theta)+U11y*Math.cos(theta+Math.PI/2);
    U1y=U11x*Math.sin(theta)+U11y*Math.sin(theta+Math.PI/2);


    U2x=U22x*Math.cos(theta)+U22y*Math.cos(theta+Math.PI/2);
    U2y=U22x*Math.sin(theta)+U22y*Math.sin(theta+Math.PI/2);

   a.setVelocityy((float)U1y);
   b.setVelocityy((float)U2y);

    a.setVelocityx((float)U1x);
    b.setVelocityx((float)U2x);

  }
```

Although the code works but the velocity I'am getting after collision seems to be as if it is  in one dimension  and from what i have understand in 2 dimension elastic collision is that the motion of the balls after collision should be perpendicular to each other which I'm not getting

for example if ball one moves with speedx 10 and speedy 0 
and ball two moves with speedx -10 and speedy -5 
the velocities I'm getting after collision is: 
 ball one becomes with speedx -10 and speedy -5

and ball two becomes with speedx 10 and speedy zero (assuming both balls have same mass)

any help or any link for a source code that works would be great
thx in advance


EDIT:in the code the U1x,U1y,U2x,U2y are the x and y velocity after collision which i need to calculate for the two balls

Comment: plz tell me which lines of code u didn't understand

Comment: For example this line `Math.cos(V1angle-theta)*Math.abs(V1);`, why do you call `Math#abs` on `V1`? I don't think that `V1` can be negative. The other problem is, that you have a lot of uncommented formulas. It is possible to understand it, but it would take some time and this might reduce the will of an volunteer to help you with this code.

Comment: I just edit it if u could check it please

Comment: *is that the motion of the balls after collision should be perpendicular to each other*, I don't think that's true. If the two balls collide exactly face-to-face, they would result in exactly the same direction.

Comment: you're right :) i just checked a tuterial on elastic collsion and found out that my code actually works :)